# iptables chains with number ranges

Tags: iptables

I run iptables-save and backup my iptables rules in git. I recently noticed that 2 new tables popped up, mangle and nat, and I was not able to delete those tables. (perhaps an update to iptables added this).

I would like to understand why these tables' chains have ranges and what those ranges mean. i.e `:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1344:400539]`. I'm not sure what 1344:400539 indicate.

When I run iptables-save, i get the following output

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1344:400539]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1344:400539]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [986:220524]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [986:220524]
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/iptables/iptables-save.c?id=d89dc47ab3875f6fe6679cebceccd2000bf81b8e#n95 you can see that those are the packet and byte-counts that have matched those chains, respectively.

```
printf("[%llu:%llu]\n", (unsigned long long)count.pcnt, (unsigned long long)count.bcnt);
```